# Npm start runs multiple instances of Node process on my windows machine

Tags: node.js, windows, windows-10

Im working on a node js application but anytime i npm start it creates a new node process causing me to get previous results from my code even after i have made changes to my code. It has made my work flow this way:
1. make changes to code
2. terminate all node js processes in the task manager
3. run npm start
4. repeat.

How can i have only one instance of node process running in my task manager or how do i make sure my new code changes work after an npm start so i wont have to exit all node processes.

Comment: It's obvious that you have to terminate your program before you start new instance? Not sure how are you starting it but it shouldn't be done using task manager ...

Comment: I terminate my npm start with Ctrl+C

Comment: I think you need to use [nodeman](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon) if you don't want to stop and restart your application. nodemon will watch the files in the directory in which nodemon was started, and if any files change, nodemon will automatically restart your node application.

Comment: @RalphMarvinAddo...did you ever get this problem solved? If so how?

Comment: No i never got the problem solved. My workaround is using Windows Task Manager to Kill the node process

Comment: No i never got the problem solved. My workaround is using Windows Task Manager to Kill the node process